# Javascript passing var on click in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to pass a variable when a `<tr>` in clicked, am getting "undefined". 
Works if I remove the `onclick="fnselect()"` and use a submit button, which I don't want.

```js
function highlight(e) {
  if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
  e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}

var table = document.getElementById('table'),
  selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function fnselect(){
  var phpValue = $("tr.selected td:first" ).html();
  window.location.href = "http://website/test.php?phpValue="+phpValue;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
     <tr onclick="fnselect()">
      <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>
      <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>F138</td>
      <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
     </tr>
     <tr onclick="fnselect()">
      <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>
      <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>F138</td>
      <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
     </tr>
     <tr onclick="fnselect()">
      <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>
      <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>F138</td>
      <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: where you are getting undefined?

Comment: there is no `tr` with a `class` of `.selected` - is this the entire HTML?

Comment: you need to include jquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tr does not become selected when you click it. You can pass the tr object to function instead:

```
<tr onclick="fnselect(this)">
```

and

```
function fnselect(obj){
  var phpValue = obj.cells[0].innerHTML;
  window.location.href = "http://website/test.php?phpValue="+phpValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Why does the fnselect(this) need the "this"?

Comment: `this` passes the current element (here is tr) to the target function.

Answer (score 2):

use Jquery which is flexible and easy to use

```js
function fun1(elem){

var result=$(elem).find("td").first().text();
alert(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr onclick="fun1(this)">
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="fun1(this)">
<td>C</td>
<td>D</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I added "this" to my tr - `onclick="fnselect(this)"` and then switched out my var for `var result=$(elem).find("td").first().text();`. It then selected and passed the variable to the new page!

Comment: Welcome Friend. If the Answer is correct than tick the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference of `this` in the `onclick`, which is a reference to the clicked `tr`

Then in `fnselect` you can wrap the passed in row reference in a jQuery object and get the html() of the first `<td>` for that row.

```js
function highlight(e) {
  if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
  e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}

var table = document.getElementById('table'),
  selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function fnselect(row){
  var phpValue = $(row).find("td:first").text();
  console.log(phpValue)
  //window.location.href = "http://website/test.php?phpValue="+phpValue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
     <tr onclick="fnselect(this)">
      <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>
      <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>F138</td>
      <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
     </tr>
     <tr onclick="fnselect(this)">
      <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>
      <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>F138</td>
      <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
     </tr>
     <tr onclick="fnselect(this)">
      <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
      <td>1 000€</td>
      <td>1 200€</td>
      <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>F138</td>
      <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```